# An example of the Pseudo-inverse of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, pseudoinverse

Let $E$ an **infinite dimensional** complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{L}(E)$  be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$.

**Definition:** Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$. The Moore-Penrose inverse of $T$, denoted by $T^{+}$, is defined as the unique linear extension of $(\overline{T})^{-1}$ in
 $$D(T^{+}) = \mathcal{R}(T)+\mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp},$$
with $\mathcal{N}(T^{+}) = \mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp}$ and  $\overline{T}$ is the isomorphism
$$\overline{T}:=T|_{{\mathcal{N}(T)}^{\perp}}: {\mathcal{N}(T)}^{\perp} \longrightarrow \mathcal{R}(T).$$
Moreover, $T^{+}$ is the unique solution of the four ''Moore-Penrose equations'':
$$TXT = T,\quad XTX = X,\quad XT = P_{N{(T)^{\bot}}}\,\,\mbox{and}\,\,\quad TX = P_{\overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}}{{|}_{D(T^{+})}}.$$

Here $\mathcal{R}(T)$ and $\mathcal{N}(T)$ denote respectively the range and the nullspace of $T$. Also $P_{F}$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $F$.

> I want to see with **an example** how we compute $T^{+}$ when $T$ is a non invertible operator acting on an **infinite dimensional** complex Hilbert space $E$.

Comment: What about $T\in L(L^2(0,1))$, $(Tx)(t) = tx(t)$, then $(T^\dagger x)(t) = t^{-1}x(t)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take $T\in B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ given by $Te_n=\tfrac1n e_n$ on the canonical orthonormal basis, that is 
$$
T(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_1,\tfrac12 x_2,\tfrac13 x_3,\ldots), 
$$
then 
$$
T^+(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_1,2 x_2,3 x_3,\ldots).
$$
A very natural example is given by the shift: if $S$ is the unilateral shift
$$
S(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(0,x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots), 
$$
then one can check directly from the Moore-Penrose equations that $S^+=S^*$, i.e., 
$$
S^+(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_2,x_3,\ldots). 
$$

Comment: Thank you for the examples. In the definition we have $$D(T^{+}) = \mathcal{R}(T)+\mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp}. $$ This means the direct sum between $ \mathcal{R}(T)$ and $\mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp}$? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The phrase "unique extension in $\mathcal R(T)+\mathcal R(T)^\perp$" means to extend it as zero on $\mathcal R(T)^\perp$. As for "direct sum", yes, in the sense that the intersection of any subspace and its orthogonal is $\{0\}$.

Comment: I think in your two examples the domain of $T^{+}$ is equal to $E$. Please correct me if I made a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: No, that's not correct. In the first example the domain is the range of $T $, which is dense but not everything.  But yes, whenever $T^+$ is bounded, its domain is the whole space.

Comment: In your first example, I think that the domain of $T^+$ is given by $$D(T^+)=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in \ell^2\,;\;(x_1, 2x_2, 3x_3, \ldots)\in \ell^2 \}.$$ However, I don't see why it is equal to the range of $T$. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: $$\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in \ell^2\,;\;(x_1, 2x_2, 3x_3, \ldots)\in \ell^2 \}=\{(x_1,\tfrac12x_2,\tfrac13x_3,\cdots)\in \ell^2\,;\;(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)\in \ell^2 \}. $$

Answer (score 0):

The following example is a solution to an exercise from [here](https://www.uni-muenster.de/AMM/num/Vorlesungen/IP_WS07/blatt7.pdf) (in German, taken from lectures at LMU Munich, 2007).

> For $a < b \in \mathbb{R}$ let
>       \begin{equation*}
>     T: L^2(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}, \ 
>     f \mapsto \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx.
> \end{equation*}

We have
    \begin{equation*}
    \ker(T)
    = \left\{ f \in L^2: \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(a,b)}(x)  dx = 0 \right\}
    = \{ \mathbb{1}_{(a,b)} \}^{\perp}
\end{equation*}
    thus
    \begin{equation*}
    \ker(T)^{\perp} 
    = \{ \mathbb 1_{(a,b)} \}^{\perp \perp}
    = \{ f: (a,b) \to \mathbb K, f(x) = c \in \mathbb{R} \ \forall x \in (a,b) \}, 
\end{equation*}
    i.e. $\ker(T)^{\perp}$ consists of all constant functions on $(a,b)$.
    We have $\text{ran}(T) = \mathbb{R}$ and thus $\text{ran}(T)^{\perp} = \{0\}$.
    Therefore
    \begin{equation*}
    \widetilde{T}: \ker(T)^{\perp} \to \mathbb{R}, \ 
    \big(f(x) = c\big) \mapsto \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx
    = (b - a) c,
\end{equation*}
    implying
    \begin{equation*}
    T^+ = \widetilde{T}^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \to \ker(T)^{\perp}, \ 
    c \mapsto \left(f(x) := \frac{c}{b-a}\right).
\end{equation*}

> Now let $w = (w_i)_{i = 1}^{n} \subset L^2(a,b)$ be an orthonormal system and consider
>       \begin{equation*}
>     T: L^2(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^n, \ 
>     f \mapsto \left( \int_{a}^{b} f(x) w_i(x) dx\right)_{i = 1}^{n}.
> \end{equation*}

As above, $\text{ran}(T) = \mathbb{R}^n$.
    Furthermore
    \begin{equation*}
    \ker(T)
    = \{ f \in L^2(a,b): \langle f, w_i \rangle = 0 \ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}\} 
    = w^{\perp}
\end{equation*}
    and thus $\ker(T)^{\perp} = w^{\perp \perp} = \text{span}(w)$.
    Then
    \begin{align*}
    \widetilde{T}: \text{span}(w) \to \mathbb{R}^n, \ 
    \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k w_k(x)
    & \mapsto \left( \int_{a}^{b} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k w_k(x) w_i(x) dx \right)_{i = 1}^{n} \\
    & = \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k \langle  w_k, w_i \rangle \right)_{i = 1}^{n} 
    = (a_i)_{i = 1}^{n},
\end{align*}
    holds as $\langle w_i, w_j \rangle = \delta_{i,j}$ since $w$ is orthonormal.
    Thus
    \begin{equation*}
    T^+ = \widetilde{T}^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \text{span}(w), \ 
    (a_i)_{i = 1}^{n} \mapsto \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k w_k(x)
\end{equation*}